# Log out via GET requests is deprecated and will be removed in Django 5.0

Tags: python, django

I get this warning while running tests with selenium and pytest. Here's the test method:

```
def test_registration(
    self, driver, live_server, valid_user_data, django_user_model
):
    selenium_signup(driver, live_server, valid_user_data, django_user_model)
    selenium_sign_in(driver, live_server, valid_user_data)
    page_source = driver.page_source.lower()
    assert 'sign in' not in page_source
    assert 'sign up' not in page_source
    assert 'sign out' in page_source
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btnGroupDrop1').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(), "Sign out")]').click()
    assert 'sign in' in page_source
    assert 'sign up' in page_source
```

This is where the warning is generated:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(), "Sign out")]').click()
```

Here's the button:

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href={% url 'signout' %}>Sign out</a></li>
```

The view uses django [LogoutView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView:%7E:text=class-,LogoutView,-%C2%B6) and here's how it's defined

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('signout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='signout'),
    ...
]
```

What would be a clean way to fix this?

Comment: Just use `POST` request instead of `GET`.

Comment: The button is clicked which in turn sends a `GET`. Where do you suggest I should I specify `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

As the doc mentioned, you must make the `HTTP POST` API call. So, it would be best if you replaced the *"hyperlink"* with a ***"button"*** (or something similar that simulates the `HTTP POST` request).

I would go with s simple button implementation, as below.

```
# logout-confirmation.html

<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Sign Out</button>
</form>
```

```py
# views.py

class LogOutRenderView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "logout-confirmation.html"
```

```py
#urls.py

from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
from .vies import LogOutRenderView

urlpatterns = [
    path("logout-confirmation/", LogOutRenderView.as_view(), name="logout-confirmation"),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    
]
```

**Note**: You can replace the hyperlink with the `<form...> ... </form>` block.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to click the button? Or are you fine with just submitting a POST request to the url that the button uses?

If so, you can create a dummy form with javascript to mimic the submit button:

```
# Fetch CSRF token from cookies
csrf_token = driver.get_cookie('csrftoken')['value']

# Inject a form using JavaScript that posts to the logout URL with a CSRF token
js_script = f"""
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = 'post';
    form.action = '/signout/';

    var csrfInput = document.createElement('input');
    csrfInput.type = 'hidden';
    csrfInput.name = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken';
    csrfInput.value = '{csrf_token}';
    form.appendChild(csrfInput);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
"""
driver.execute_script(js_script)
```